# C++ Class inheritance "expected class-name" error

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation

My previous question was asked wrong, so I'll post it fixed.
I have this example throwing 
`expected class-name before ‘{’ token`
error while compiling. I am understanding why is it fails, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you.
**BaseClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H

#include "ElementClass.h"

class ElementClass;

class BaseClass
{

private:
    ElementClass *m_someField;
};


#endif
```

**ElementClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H

#include "ChildClass.h"

class ChildClass;

class ElementClass
{
private:
    ChildClass *m_class;
};


#endif
```

**ChildClass.h**

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_CHILDCLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_CHILDCLASS_H

#include "BaseClass.h"

class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{

};


#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have circulary dependent .h files.

In BaseClass.h:

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_BASECLASS_H

#include "ElementClass.h"  // Includes ElementClass.h
```

In ElementClass.h:

```
#ifndef INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H
#define INHERITTEST_ELEMENTCLASS_H

#include "ChildClass.h"   // Which included BaseClass.h
```

You can remove those `#include` lines since you are using those classes by pointers only and a forward declaration is sufficient for that purpose.

Comment: But what if I'am using this objects on this pointers inside class?

Comment: Then you need the .h files. If you implement the functions that need access to the objects that these pointers point to in a .cc file, then there is no problem at all.

Comment: Wow, thanks. All that time I really thought that I have to use `#include` only in `.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with inheritance the following

```
#include "ChildClass.h"
class ChildClass;
```

is unnecessary, if you're going to break these into sepperate source files (which it looks like you are) you can say

```
#include "ElementClass.h"
```

in the source file of your derived class